# Minor video editing on Linux. How it's better to do it?

Tags: linux, video, video-editing

[Imagine] I have a compressed video file. How it's better to slightly change it? What software should I use?

Examples of tasks:

1. Make the video slowdown on some moment + draw a circle or freehand line on some part of image.
2. Blur some parts of video (e.g. censor it).
3. Fix something minor in it (manually erasing or drawing things in frames).

Features that should the video editor have:

1. Reading and demuxing compressed files (desirable without creating large temporaries).
2. Ability to "pass-throught" compressed stream without decoding+endoding it. Slight quality loss (because of reencoding) is acceptable only near the frames that was actually modified.
3. Have couple of effects *that can be applied to parts of picture of complex shape*. If "curve editor" is obvious thing that needn't be mentioned separately.
4. Ability to invoke fully-fledged external picture editor (like Gimp) for some parts of video (both spatially and temporally delimited).
5. Mux and write output files, reusing parts of compressed streams from input.

FOSS is strongly preferred. Target system is GNU/Linux (Wine is allowed). It needn't be one big intergated environment, it can be set of tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try OpenShot. I don't know about all of your needs, butvitvseems fairly solid as far as linux video editing goes. Also, its in active development. Request features that you need from the developer.

Link: http://www.openshotvideo.com/

Comment: OpenShot can't do much. Just basics. Has some effect, but quite unusable - e.g. blur can just be applied to whole track, not just some region.

Answer (score 1):

[Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/) is a quite full-featured video editor for Linux. Unfortunately it may a bit unstable - or then not. Sometimes I've used it for days without problems, but during other times it might crash very often. Also its UI is not as easy to use than with [Kino](http://www.kinodv.org/) or [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/), but after the initial learning curve it's quick to use.

For your use Kdeenlive might actually be enough.

Some people also use [Blender](http://blender.org/) for video editing - see [the manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Sequencer).

Comment: Cinelerra: http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=endscreen&v=8w5myJd2BRk  Just add a blur to the top track.

Comment: I've tried Cinelerra, and it's just the basics, too. The only advanced thing is masks. But their editing sucks, only allows polygon, makes the program crash, and when rendered, the mask polygon is screwed up anyway.

Comment: Cinelerra is unusable, crashes during rendering, can't render anything longer than 1 minute.

Comment: Kdenlive turns out to be very easy, with zero prior knowledge I used this video and learned in just a minute how to obscure parts of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irZhvdhmx-U